# Arguments in pamk function

Tags: r, machine-learning

I want to apply partitioning around medoids using r (page 95 [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/fpc.pdf)). I have a dissimilarity matrix as input. I should therefore put usepam=FALSE. However, I don't understand what inherits should be...As I have a dissimilarity matrix, I should set diss to TRUE. However, what is the `inherits` for? Since I know when I have my data matrix whether it is a similarity or a dissimilarity one, I know whether the `diss` argument should be set to TRUE or FALSE. Therefore, why do I need `inherits`?

Comment: According to the documentation you've referenced, there is no parameter called `inherits` in the function you're trying to call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature is

```
pamk(data,krange=2:10,criterion="asw", usepam=TRUE,
    scaling=FALSE, alpha=0.001, diss=inherits(data, "dist"),
    critout=FALSE, ns=10, seed=NULL, ...)
```

The parameter `diss` expects a TRUE or FALSE value. If you leave it unspecified, it will use the default value which is set to `inherits(data, "dist")`. This means that if you don't set `diss`, it will look to see if your first parameter (your `data=` value) is a class that inherits from the class `dist` to see if it might be a distance matrix. You can set an object of that type with

```
xx<-dist(matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=2));
class(xx)
```

But if you calculated your matrix in some other way, it may not have a class of "dist". The point is they are trying to see what type of object you are passing and set the correct defaults for you.